# Subset data based on partial match of column names

Tags: r, subset

I need to subset a df to include certain strings. Some of these are full column names, and the following works fine:

```
testData[,c("FullColName1","FullColName2","FullColName3")]
```

My problem is that I need to expand this to also include column names that contain specific strings that may partially match to some other column names. These strings include letters and symbols:

```
"PartString1()","PartString2()"
```

I tried putting wildcards around these. (I've indicated this below with the prefix "star" because the "*" symbol didn't render correctly.)

```
testData[ ,c("FullColName1","FullColName2","FullColName3",
             "starPartString1()star","starPartString2()star")]
```

But I'm getting an error message: `"undefined columns selected"`. I can't figure out if or how I need `grep()` to make this work.

Comment: What is "PartString1()"? The paired parentheses make me think you are using a function. It's NOT a valid R name. Try putting in code that constructs what you are working with.

Comment: "PartString1()" is a variable name. I was trying to use grep to match on partial column names that included specific char strings and a set of parentheses. Problem solved with df2<-df1[, grepl("FullColName1|FullColName2|FullColName3|PartSting1[[:punct:]]|PartString2[[:punct:]]",names(df1))]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You mentioned you may be looking for symbols, so for this particular example we can use `[[:punct:]]` as our regular expression.  This will find all the strings with punctuation symbols in the column names.

```
d <- data.frame(1:3, 3:1, 11:13, 13:11, rep(1, 3))
names(d) <- c("FullColName1", "FullColName2", "FullColName3",
              "PartString1()","PartString2()")

d[grepl("[[:punct:]]", names(d))]
#   PartString1() PartString2()
# 1            13             1
# 2            12             1
# 3            11             1
```

This last part just illustrates another way to do this with other string processing functions from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
d[str_detect(names(d), "[[:punct:]]")]
#   PartString1() PartString2()
# 1            13             1
# 2            12             1
# 3            11             1
```

**ADD** per OPs comment

```
d[grepl("ring[12()]", names(d))]
```

to get either of the substrings `ring1()` or `ring2()` from the names vector

Comment: Thanks very much Richard. I did not know about [[:punct:]]. This almost solves my problem, but I need to select all columns that have the substring ring1() or the substring ring2(). Just searching for punctuation is too broad.

Comment: That would just be `d[, grepl("ring[12()]", names(d))]`.  Would you like me to change that in my answer?

Comment: I came up with d[, grep("ring1[[:punct:]]|ring2[[:punct:]]",names(d))], but yours is more elegant. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `grep` to find indices of column names with partial match to a particular pattern

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
data(managers)

colnames(managers)
#[1] "HAM1"        "HAM2"        "HAM3"        "HAM4"        "HAM5"       
#[6] "HAM6"        "EDHEC LS EQ" "SP500 TR"    "US 10Y TR"   "US 3m TR"
```

suppose the pattern you want to match is "**HAM**", along with some fixed column names ("SP500 TR"    "US 10Y TR"   "US 3m TR")

```
head(managers[,c("SP500 TR","US 10Y TR","US 3m TR",colnames(managers)[grep("HAM",colnames(managers))])])
#           SP500 TR US 10Y TR US 3m TR    HAM1 HAM2    HAM3    HAM4 HAM5 HAM6
#1996-01-31   0.0340   0.00380  0.00456  0.0074   NA  0.0349  0.0222   NA   NA
#1996-02-29   0.0093  -0.03532  0.00398  0.0193   NA  0.0351  0.0195   NA   NA
#1996-03-31   0.0096  -0.01057  0.00371  0.0155   NA  0.0258 -0.0098   NA   NA
#1996-04-30   0.0147  -0.01739  0.00428 -0.0091   NA  0.0449  0.0236   NA   NA
#1996-05-31   0.0258  -0.00543  0.00443  0.0076   NA  0.0353  0.0028   NA   NA
#1996-06-30   0.0038   0.01507  0.00412 -0.0039   NA -0.0303 -0.0019   NA   NA
```

you can specify multiple patterns using, `grep("pattern1 | pattern2 ", colnames(data))`

Comment: thanks for showing me your multiple pattern example. I had been putting each of the patterns in quotes, rather than putting quotes around the entire set of patterns.

Comment: In my application, I had to write ``grep("pattern1|pattern2 ", colnames(data))``, *without*  a space either side of ``|``

Answer (score 4):

You can use `grepl` for a search by column name.  It returns a logical vector indicating matches.

Here is an example:

```
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE,
                text="1PartString()2 1PartString()3 OtherCol
                1 2 3
                3 4 5")
d
##   1PartString()2 1PartString()3 OtherCol
## 1              1              2        3
## 2              3              4        5

d[,grepl("PartString\\(\\)", names(d))]
##   1PartString()2 1PartString()3
## 1              1              2
## 2              3              4
```

`grepl` check to see if the pattern is present anywhere in the name, so a wildcard is not required.

Comment: Or just use patt="PartString". The notion of putting paired parentheses in dataframe column names just seems so wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The question asked is how to retrieve specific column names, given only partial strings.  Let me offer a simple `grepl` solution.

```
#example data
 df <- data.frame(col1_sse = paste0(1:5, LETTERS[1:5]),
            col2_swl = runif(5, max = 10), 
            col3_sdz = runif(5, max = 1000),
            col4_swl = paste0(letters[1:5]))

#assume partial names are complex
 partial_names <- c("2_sw", "sdz")

#create a "keepers" list of column names
 keepers <- names(df)[grepl(paste0(partial_names, collapse = "|"), names(df))]

#use "keepers" to extract cols from original data 
 new_df <- df[,keepers]
```